# Getting PGP private key

Tags: pgp

I would like to know how data encryption and decryption works in PGP. As part of encryption, "gpg --gen-key" is used to generate the keys, And I got a public key, however I am not sure how to get private key. does it store in a specific location? is there any command to generate? I don't have any clue.

This is not specified in the document that I am following.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The private key is not "visible" like the public one, but you can get it following these instructions:

You can list private keys this way, in order to check if it exists:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

And you can make it visible doing a backup of your keys:

```
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys your_email@domain.com > your_name.asc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could get it using the following command.
"sudo gpg --armor --export-secret-keys "name (comment) <email_id>" > filename.asc"

Comment: This option doesn't show up in the help output, it is really "secret". I think it should be added.